# Need help in string parsing (regex)

Tags: java, regex

I hava a string `cd   /Users/bob/temp` and I need to parse it to a string array, but

- my input string may begin by any number of spaces (    cd)
- between "cd" and path can be any number of spaces (cd
  /Users/bob/temp)
- path may contain any character, including dor       (for hidden
  directories)

My try `String[] exp = action.split("^cd++[\\w\\W]*");`

Comment: show your tried before being downvoted and closed as off the topic

Comment: What's the expected result ?

Comment: {"cd", "/Users/bob/temp"} or as an example in win {"cd", "D:\bob\temp"}

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the method `split()` on your String :

```
String s = cd /Users/bob/temp;
String[] split = s.split("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume that your tokens are `cd` and `/path/to\ my/foo/bar`.

When it comes to escaping, regular expressions aren't the best approach as they get slow and unclear. Writing a parser is usually a better way to go.

Since your string looks like bash snippet (which allows the escaping), you might rather want to take the parser way.